# odoo: I inherited hr.expense module then I want to display selected fields but it gives me an error when i try to save it. Why?

Tags: xml, python-2.7

[image: this is the screenshot on my error. please view it]

I want to display selected fields on my inherited module which is hr.expense but it gives me error when i trying to save it. I created Many2one into my inherited module which is 'hr.expense' then One2many to my new module.

This is my .py

```
class Items (models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.expense'

    items_id = fields.Many2one('account.pettycash.request', string="Items")

class PettyCashRequest (models.Model):
    _name = 'account.pettycash.request'

    items_ids = fields.One2many('hr.expense', 'items_id', string="Items")

    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', "Draft"),
        ('confirmed', "Confirmed"),
        ('approved', "Aprroved"),])

    @api.multi
```

In my XML, i call my One2many field which is item_ids then in it, I call selected fields that hr.expense have which are product_id, unit_amount and quantity.
this is my xml.

```
                        <page string="Items">
                            <field name="items_ids">
                                 <tree editable = "bottom">
                                     <field name = "product_id"/>
                                     <field name = "unit_amount"/>
                                     <field name = "quantity"/>
                                 </tree>

                                 <form>
                                     <sheet>
                                         <group>
                                             <field name = "product_id"/>
                                             <field name = "unit_amount"/>
                                             <field name = "quantity"/>
                                         </group>
                                     </sheet>
                                 </form>
                             </field>
                         </page>
                     </notebook>
```

Answer (score 0):

Odoo is complaining about "domain in state, 'not in', ('draft', 'refused')".
You have inherited a state field, but 'refused' is not there. So I check hr_expense module and state field is like this.

```
state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'To Submit'),
        ('reported', 'Reported'),
        ('done', 'Posted'),
        ('refused', 'Refused')
        ], compute='_compute_state', string='Status', copy=False, index=True, readonly=True, store=True,
help="Status of the expense.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically because of the field named 'state' and not because of the field 'item_ids'

Problem: You are using the 'state' field in some domain. Odoo searches for its deceleration in the view but can't find one.
Odoo asks you to first declare the field in the view and then use it in domain attribute.

What you can do is at the beginning where you have started creating the form write

```
<field name='state'/>
```

What I usually do is:

```
<form string='FormString'>
   <header>

     <!-- Decleration of fields in the view -->

     <field name='state'/>
     <field name='items_id'/>
   </header>

   <!-- Code for my form view -->
</form>
```